# Migrating users from the current cognito pool to a new one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Suppose we have a cognito user pool we setup and we realize that we forgot to add an attribute.

We create a new pool with the attribute added. How do we migrate the users to the new pool?

Comment: Do your users have a user profile or something in a db with user details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a lambda that pulls your users in a manageable chunk.

Take each user's info and add the user to the new user pool using the admin js add here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html

You should be able to force confirm their phone and email, as well as add any missing attributes on creation with the admin api.